# Elasticsearch : search for sets of items instead of items

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a website where I log users actions: visit page, download document, log in, etc. Each action is timestamped, attached to a user and indexed in Elasticsearch

I would like to recognize predefined patterns in thoses actions. eg:

- find users who visited this page, this other page and downloaded 2 documents in the last 3 weeks
- find users who logged in and visited at least 5 pages in the same day

The problem I have is I always used ES to find items that match criterias but never to find set of items.

How would you start to solve this problem ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add your mapping and what you have tried so far to get a clear answer and not hypotheticals

Comment: Hi. Thank your for the comment. I have not yet written any code to build this. It is the first time I do search on groups of items instead of items and I am looking more for approach ideas and clues than for clear answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the second query I would suggest aggregations (like SQL GROUP BY): count the number of page visits aggregated per user and day.
And then add conditions on these aggregated results (like SQL HAVING)

To filter on aggregation results I found this (not tested or tried to understand:):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Hope it helps